# how to make the edges appear in a line evenly while uv unwrapping

Tags: uv, vertices, edges, faces

I am a noob to blender. I am working on a project which involves getting precise dimensions of a 3D object and for that I am practicing UV Unwrapping.

All the UV unwrapping tutorials I have watched have even edges on the objects they unwrap. As you can see in the 2 pictures below.

[image]

[image]

However, when I imported a 3D model ( it is a .obj file) to practice unwrapping, my edges look something like this. Can someone nudge me in the right direction on how can I make my edges line up evenly. I would make marking the seams whole lot simpler.

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of any silver bullet answer to this issue. What this model needs is re-topologising, or re-modelling from scratch with this used as a template or base to ensure good topology like what you'd need. There are techniques for retopologising in Blender, but I'd sooner to back to where you sourced this model and see if you can get one that's more tidy. It looks like it may have been photoscanned?

Comment: This mesh is not quad-based, and looks like it is non-manifold. I don't think it is really salvageable. I wouldn't waste my time practising UV unwrapping using this, there is no real world scenario where you would want to manually UV-unwrap such a mess IMO :)

Comment: @Onyx yes, this model was created using photogrammetry. I sourced it from this 3D scanner app called KIRI Engine and this is for practice. I am planning to use the same app to scan the actual product (Camera) that I want dimensions for.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks.. I looked up and it seems like what I have is a triangle-based mesh but I need a quad-based. I suppose the right course of action would be to go back and source a clean mesh or a quad based.

Comment: Photogrammetry can't output a clean, quad based mesh. You will need to remesh it using manual retopology or an automatic remesher like quad remesher or instant meshes